# React Native saveToCameraRoll failed with `Permission denied` error on Android

Tags: react-native

#### Description

saveToCameraRoll failed with `Permission denied` error on Android

#### Reproduction

Saving a AWS S3 photo to the device Camera Roll suddenly failed

```
RNFS.downloadFile(DownloadFileOptions)
            .promise
            .then(() => {
                 CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(path, this.state.type) // path = /data/user/0/com.XXX.app/filesimage-xyz.jpg"
                    .then((data) => {
                        RNFS.unlink(path)
                            .then(() => {
                                console.log('Download and file unlink succeeded');
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                                console.error("RNFS unlink error: ", err.message);
                            });
                        })
                    .catch((error) => { 
                        console.error("Save to Cameral roll  error: ",error.message); 
//error = code:"EUNSPECIFIED"
// framesToPop:1
// message:"Permission denied"
// stack:"Error: Permission denied↵  
                    });
                })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("RNFS.downloadFile! error: ", error.message);
            });
```

In the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml i have 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
among few other permissions.

What can cause a permission denied error ? what shall be done at the Manifest level to save to cameraRoll ?

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: [FILL THIS OUT: Does the bug reproduce on the latest RN release?]
  Check with V41
- Platform: [FILL THIS OUT: iOS, Android, or both?]
  Android inly
- Operating System: [FILL THIS OUT: MacOS, Linux, or Windows?]
  Dev MacOS Sierra
- Dev tools: [FILL THIS OUT: Xcode or Android Studio version, iOS or Android SDK version, if applicable]
  RN CLI + Android SDK

Answer (score 12):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. You can use [PermissionAndroid API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html) to let users to grant permission for external storage access.

Example:

```
  requestExternalStoragePermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'My App Storage Permission',
          message: 'My App needs access to your storage ' +
            'so you can save your photos',
        },
      );
      return granted;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to request permission ', err);
      return null;
    }
  };
```

Comment: It works and should be marked as accepted answer, I believe! Also we probably need to perform `Platform.OS` check as well as permission request is only needed on Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
...
let permission = await Expo.Permissions.askAsync(Expo.Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

if (permission.status === 'granted') {
   await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(fileUrl, "photo");
}
```